# Updating all packages resulted in a lot of errors, is it possible to roll back to previous R packages version

Tags: r, r-package

I catastrophically upgraded the packages in Rstudio using `update.packages(ask=FALSE, dependencies=TRUE)`.

When I re-run many of my R scripts, I found a lot of version conflicts and function not found errors. E.g:

> Error in `mutate()`: ! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything(), ~replace_na(., "date"))`. Caused by error in
> `across()`: ! Problem while computing column `...1`. Caused by error
> in `replace_na()`: ! could not find function "replace_na"
>
> Error in spread(., rowname, value) : could not find function "spread"
>
> Error: C stack usage 15926560 is too close to the limit

If I don't want to fix each bug one by one, is it possible to roll back to the previous R packages version without backing up the previous R packages? Thanks.

**Updates:**

By upgrading **RGui**, most of the errors are solved. The upgrade method is to execute the following code in RGui:

```
install.packages("installr")
library(installr)
updateR()
```

Comment: I never had a problem with `update.packages(ask=FALSE)`, I've been using it for years. What probably happened is that your R (including RGui on Windows) was outdated, and `updateR` apparently is able to also update R (on Windows at least). There are packages out there, that constantly rename functions or their functionalities (especially `tidyverse` is known for that, which you seem to use according to your error example), try to use them less to increase the lifetime of your scripts. Always comment a `sessionInfo()` to your important scripts, consider [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: @jay.sf thanks for your advice. It may indeed be caused by my lower version of R. After upgrading of R, the errors are much less.